# Optional arguments change stack

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I define a decorator as so:

```
from inspect import stack

def decorator():
    def wrapper(function):
        print stack()[1]
        return function
    return wrapper
```

When I define a function without optional arguments like this:

```
@decorator()
def f(a):
    pass
```

it says that wrapper was called on line one, printing this:

```
(<frame object at 0x10bf9c3b0>, '<stdin>', 1, '<module>', None, None)
```

When I define the function with optional arguments:

```
@decorator()
def f(a=True):
    pass
```

it says that wrapper was called on line two, printing this:

```
(<frame object at 0x10bf08c58>, '<stdin>', 2, '<module>', None, None)
```

Why does the optional argument change the stack? Is there any way to alter one or the other so that they're the same whichever way the function is defined (keeping in mind blank lines are allowed between the decorator and the function)?

This seems to happen in every traceback function I can find, as well as in python 3 (if you change the print statement of course).

Comment: The assigment `a=True` will count as one extra line. It must be executed before decorators code.

Comment: @Marcin but when I raise an exception instead, the first one has the text for the decorator line, but the second one has the text for the definition line

Comment: @Marcin also, the stack for the decorator function stays the same; it's only the inner one that changes